# How to modify Scala actor to return List[String]?

Tags: scala, akka

Following the Akka tutorials https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/guide/tutorial_1.html I have modified sample code to send a message to an akka actor every 3 seconds:

```
  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    initialDelay = Duration(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    interval = Duration(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))(
    runnable = task)

}
```

I'm unable to safely compiling changing the message return in Main from String to List[String]. So instead of `firstRef ! "printit"` , change to `firstRef ! List("printit")` but this causes compiler error:

[image]

To fix the compiler error I make changes to:

```
class Main(context: ActorContext[String]) extends AbstractBehavior[List[String]](context) {
  override def onMessage(msg: String): Behavior[List[String]] =
def apply(): Behavior[List[String]] =
```

where previously this contained:

```
class Main(context: ActorContext[String]) extends AbstractBehavior[String](context) {
  override def onMessage(msg: String): Behavior[String] =
def apply(): Behavior[String] =
```

What needs to change in order to return `List[String]` instead of `String` in the `Main` actor ?

complete code (without changes):

```
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

    import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem
    import akka.actor.typed.Behavior
    import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AbstractBehavior
    import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.ActorContext
    import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
    import map.QTableRow

    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

    object PrintMyActorRefActor {
      def apply(): Behavior[String] =
        Behaviors.setup(context => new PrintMyActorRefActor(context))
    }

    class PrintMyActorRefActor(context: ActorContext[String]) extends AbstractBehavior[String](context) {

      override def onMessage(msg: String): Behavior[String] =
        msg match {
          case "printit" =>
            val secondRef = context.spawn(Behaviors.empty[String], "second-actor")
            println(s"Second: $secondRef")
            this
        }
    }

    object Main {
      def apply(): Behavior[String] =
        Behaviors.setup(context => new Main(context))

    }

    class Main(context: ActorContext[String]) extends AbstractBehavior[String](context) {
      override def onMessage(msg: String): Behavior[String] =
        msg match {
          case "getdata" =>

            val firstRef = context.spawn(PrintMyActorRefActor(), "first-actor"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            println(s"First: $firstRef")

            firstRef ! "printit"
            this
        }
    }

    object ActorHierarchyExperiments extends App {
      val testSystem = ActorSystem(Main(), "testSystem")
      val scheduler = testSystem.scheduler

      val task = new Runnable { def run() {

        testSystem ! "getdata" }

      }

      scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        initialDelay = Duration(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
        interval = Duration(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))(
        runnable = task)

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `firstRef` actor reference references an instance of `PrintMyActorRefActor`, which is a `Behavior[ String ]`, so to send any `List[ String ]`to the ref, the `PrintMyActorRefActor` needs to be able to recieve it. Changing this, including the signature of its `recieve` message, should make the snippet compile. Now, of course, you'll need to change the behaviour of the `PrintMyActorRefActor.onMessage( msg: List[ String ] ): Behavior[ List[ String ] ]` to deal with the list instead of the single string...

Complete transformed code snippet:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.{AbstractBehavior, ActorContext, Behaviors}
import akka.actor.typed.{ActorSystem, Behavior}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object PrintMyActorRefActor {
  def apply(): Behavior[List[String]] =
    Behaviors.setup(context => new PrintMyActorRefActor(context))
}

class PrintMyActorRefActor(context: ActorContext[List[String]]) extends AbstractBehavior[List[String]](context) {

  override def onMessage(msg: List[String]): Behavior[List[String]] =
    msg match {
      case "printit" :: xs => // ignores all but the head element
        val secondRef = context.spawn(Behaviors.empty[String], "second-actor")
        println(s"Second: $secondRef")
        this
    }
}

object Main {
  def apply(): Behavior[String] =
    Behaviors.setup(context => new Main(context))

}

class Main(context: ActorContext[String]) extends AbstractBehavior[String](context) {
  override def onMessage(msg: String): Behavior[String] =
    msg match {
      case "getdata" =>

        val firstRef = context.spawn(PrintMyActorRefActor(), "first-actor" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        println(s"First: $firstRef")

        firstRef ! List("printit")
        this
    }
}

object ActorHierarchyExperiments extends App {
  val testSystem = ActorSystem(Main(), "testSystem")
  val scheduler = testSystem.scheduler

  val task = new Runnable {
    def run() {
      testSystem ! "getdata"
    }
  }

  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    initialDelay = Duration(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    interval = Duration(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))(
    runnable = task)
}
```

Comment: thanks, in your code 'case "printit" :: xs => // ignores all but the head element' can I match on the entire List and assign it to a variable so I can use it, instead of matching on splitting the list into head and tail ?

Comment: Yes, you can: ```case xs =>``` matches the entire list into the variable ```xs```. You can then use it however you'd normally use a list